# "Selected" style of textfield

Tags: textfield, codenameone

I am evaluating Codename One for our product and struggling to do one simple thing.

I need colour of border and text of textfield to be blue when field is focused or when I am typing in some text. However, field absolutely behaves like Pressed instead of Selected. So when I'm tapping on the field the style is correct, but when and releasing my finger from that field it turns into Unselected style.

See screenshots of my builder:

[image]
[image]

You can see that even in preview it's not blue for some reason, same in preview on the right, simulator, and on real device (iPad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work I had to set includeNativeBool constant to false. Style is shown correctly on real device, but in Simulator text still is black instead of colour that I set.

**UPDATE:**

As Shai advised unsetting of includeNativeBool is not a correct solution even though it changes behaviour. Setting of pureTouchBool to false is a right way to go.

Comment: That's not the right approach. You can use Display.setPureTouch(false) to get a feature phone behavior or use pureTouchBool=false theme constant.

Comment: There is still same issue with simulator, simulator does not set correct colour when typing text in. However, real device does.

Comment: The simulator tries to highlight that the editing is handled in the native platform and is thus less customizable than the rest of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Selection on touch devices is only rendered when the user actually touches the device and hidden when there is no interaction. You can disable that behavior but that's probably not what you want to do and isn't the convention on touch devices such as iOS devices.